# Virtual keyboard not working on Microsoft Surface hardware but does work in the simulator

Tags: wpf, textbox, pixelsense, virtual-keyboard

I did an application for the Microsoft Surface and the virtual keyboard that appears when I focus the SurfaceTextBox did not appear when I tested it on a real Microsoft Surface yesterday. On the simulator it works fine and without any problems.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804971(v=surface.10).aspx That article describes how to test an application in admin mode. That should help. Posted here again for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual keyboard is presented from the surface shell. How have you tested your program? In user mode or administration mode? If you have done this in application mode make sure you have started the shell and registered your application with it (xml file in %PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Surface\Programs).

Comment: I have the same problem as Sofri. Im running admin mode. So waht do do?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804971(v=surface.10).aspx That article describes how to test an application in admin mode. That should help.